# Certain characters making php string mess up

Tags: php, html, xhtml

I have a foreach loop that spits out all of the "read mail" in a user's inbox:

```
        foreach ($tmpArray as $array) {
            if ($array['message_parent_id'] == 0) {
                $convo = $this->model->getConvoArray($array['message_id']);
                $array['message_datetime'] = $convo[sizeof($convo) - 1]['message_datetime'];
                $lastMessage = $this->model->getLastReply($array['message_id']);
                if ($_SESSION['username'] == $lastMessage['message_sender']) {
                    $messageBody = "<b>&lArr;</b> " . $lastMessage['message_body'];
                } else {
                    $messageBody = $lastMessage['message_body'];
                }
                $array['message_body'] = $messageBody;
            }
            array_push($readMail, $array);
            //echo PrettyDate::convert($array['message_datetime']);
            //echo "<br />";
        }
```

However, when $lastMessage['message_body'] == "<(^_^<) Kirby!" I get $array['message_body'] == "by!".  But when $lastMessage['message_body'] == "<(^_ Kirby!" it is stored into $array['message_body'] correctly as "<(^_ Kirby!".  Not entirely sure what's going on.  All other cases I've tried work fine.

It works when I take out  around &lArr.  I'm guessing it's something to do with that.

Comment: Perhaps that's what you think there is. Try viewing the source of your page, instead of the original outcome (with right click -> view source)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap $lastMessage['message_body'] in htmlentities() and it should solve your problem.

```
$lastMessage['message_body'] = htmlentities($lastMessage['message_body']);
```

Comment: This didn't work.  I thought it did, but it wouldn't give me the $lArr; I took the <b></b> and it works fine, though.

Answer (score 1):

Since this string has a > in it, the browser could be seeing it as a HTML element. To fix this pass `$lastMessage['message_body']` through [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/htmlentities):

```
htmlentities($lastMessage['message_body']);
```